# Sound settings in Android

Tags: android, settings

I would like to reach the sound settings and get change the volume.
How can i do that by code?

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

you can find all system settings in this cursor:

```
Cursor Settingscursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(Settings.System.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: mContext its the Context of the application

Answer (score 0):

Lore,

You want [`AudioManager.adjustVolume()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#adjustVolume%28int,%20int%29).